# MUI grid not stacking side by side in dynamic form

Tags: material-ui

This seems like a noob question, but for some reason, In my form, the grid is not stacking side by side when i set the prop to 6 IE md={6}. They all just set themselves to 6, and goto the next line. What i want, is for them to be side by side.

```
            {fieldSet.map((item,index) => {
                if(item.domain === null){
                  if(item.alias == 'OBJECTID'){
                    return
                  };
                    return (
                        <Grid xs={12} md={6} lg={6} key={index}>
                            <FormControl variant="standard" fullWidth style={{marginBottom:'10px'}}>
                            <InputLabel shrink multiline htmlFor={item.alias} style={{color:'white'}}>{item.alias}</InputLabel>
                            <StyledInput id={item.alias} onChange={e => setFieldsData(fieldsData => ({...fieldsData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value}))} />
                            </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                    )
                } else if(item.domain != null){
                    return (
                        <Grid xs={12} md={6} lg={6} key={index}>
                            <FormControl fullWidth size='small' style={{marginTop:'20px'}}>
                            <InputLabel id={item.alias}>{item.alias}</InputLabel>
                            <Select id={item.alias} labelId={item.alias} onChange={e => setFieldsData(fieldsData => ({...fieldsData, [item.alias]: e.target.value}))} style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                              {item.domain.codedValues.map((values, index) => {
                                return (
                                  <MenuItem key={index} value={values.name}>{values.name}</MenuItem>
                                )
                              })}
                            </Select>
                            </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                    )
                }
            })}
```

Comment: I think you're missing the `item` prop to indicate that its a grid item

Comment: I was using grid2 at the time, but ive added the original grid, and added the item prop. Still wont. It works outside of the loop, but not inside.

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.